# Complex Integral: Why does $\bigg\lvert \int_a^b f(z) dz \ \bigg\rvert \le \int_a^b \bigg\lvert f(z) \bigg\rvert dz$hold?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, inequality

> I am asking myself why for a complex number $z$ and real numbers $a \le b$ holds
>
> $$\bigg\lvert \int_a^b f(z) dz \ \bigg\rvert \le \int_a^b \bigg\lvert f(z) \bigg\rvert dz$$

I know that this holds for real numbers, but I do not see how we can transfer this to the real and imaginary part of $f$, but I do not see how. Could you help me?

Comment: Comes from the definition of the integral. Like many integral identities, you have to jump down to the Riemann definition to prove it.

Comment: Before proving it you need to know what can be proven. The notation in the title is not usual, so it could be defined to make the statement true. The statement in the body of the problem is common notation, but it is false in general. The left hand side is a real number, while the right hand side can be a non-real complex number. The inequality that is true and is similar looking to what you wrote is $|\int_{a}^{b}f(z)dz|=|\int_{0}^{1}f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)dt|\leq\int_{0}^{1}|f(\gamma(t))||\gamma'(t)|dt$, where $\gamma$ is a parametrization of the segment from $a$ to $b$.

Comment: The last integral sometimes people denote it as $\int_{a}^{b}|f(z)|d|z|$ or $\int_{a}^{b}|f(z)||dz|$, or some similar choice of the writer.

Comment: @conditionalMethod: Sorry for the trouble, it was just a typo.

Comment: Well, now it has everywhere the statement that is potentially false, unless it is assumed that we are talking about the particular case linked above, in which $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and the path between $a$ and $b$ is the segment $[a,b]$ in the real numbers.

Comment: Yes I meant that. I'll make an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to prove is that for a function $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{C}$ holds
$$\left| \int_a^b f(t) dt \right| \leq \int_a^b \left| f(t) \right| dt.$$
Note that I changed the integration variable from $z$ to $t$ because $z$ is normally used for integration over curve integrals, where $z$ is complex in general. But here $a$ and $b$ are real numbers and the integral here is just a Riemann integral (not a curve integral) and thus the integration variable $t$ is real.

Now let $re^{i\theta} = \int_a^b f(t) dt$ be the polar representation of the value of the integral. Thus, $e^{-i\theta}\int_a^b f(t) dt \in \mathbb{R}$. Note that $\left|e^{-i\theta}\right| = 1$. Now we can estimate:

$$\left| \int_a^b f(t) dt \right| = \left| e^{-i\theta} \right| \left| \int_a^b f(t) dt \right| = \left| e^{-i\theta} \int_a^b f(t) dt \right| = \left| \Re\left( e^{-i\theta} \int_a^b f(t) dt \right) \right| = \left| \Re\left( \int_a^b e^{-i\theta}f(t) dt \right) \right| = \left| \int_a^b \Re\left(e^{-i\theta}f(t)\right) dt  \right| \leq \int_a^b \left| \Re\left(e^{-i\theta}f(t)\right)\right| dt \leq \int_a^b \left| e^{-i\theta}f(t)\right| dt = \int_a^b \left| f(t)\right| dt$$